# Getting 'java.lang.NullPointerException' on executing test Cases

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, page-objects

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import com.ebay.qa.base.TestBase1;
    import com.ebay.qa.pages.HomePage;
    import com.ebay.qa.pages.SigninPage;

    public class SigninPageTest extends TestBase1 {

        SigninPage signinPage;
        HomePage homePage;
        public WebDriver driver;
        public SigninPageTest() {
            super();
        }


        @BeforeMethod
        public void setup() {
            initialization();
            SigninPage signinPage = new SigninPage();
        }

        @Test

        public void SigninPageTitleTest() throws InterruptedException {
        String title =  signinPage.valiadateSigninPagetitle();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Assert.assertEquals(title, "Sign in or Register");
        }
        @Test
            public void EbaylogoimgTest() {
            boolean logo = signinPage.ebayimage();
            Assert.assertTrue(logo);
            }
        @Test
        public void SigninTest() {
       homePage =   signinPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));

        }




        @AfterMethod
        public void teardown() {
            if (driver != null) {
                //You might want to debug this though
                driver.quit();
                }

        }


        }
```

==========================================================================
SIGN IN  PAGE

```
package com.ebay.qa.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.ebay.qa.base.TestBase1;

public class SigninPage extends TestBase1{

    //define page factory or Object repository
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='userid']")
    WebElement username;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='pass']")
    WebElement password;
    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@id='sgnBt']")
    WebElement submitBtn;


    @FindBy (xpath = "//a[@id='InLineCreateAnAccount']")
    WebElement createanAccount;

    @FindBy(xpath ="//img[conatains(@id='gh-logo')]")
    WebElement ebaylogo;

    public SigninPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        //this means current class objects

    }

    public String valiadateSigninPagetitle() 
    {
        return driver.getTitle();
    }
    public boolean ebayimage()
    {
        return ebaylogo.isDisplayed();
    }
    public HomePage login(String un, String pwd)
    {
        username.sendKeys(un);
        password.sendKeys(pwd);
        submitBtn.click();
        return new HomePage();
    }






}
```

==========================================================================
TESTBASE1

```
package com.ebay.qa.base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;

import com.ebay.qa.util.TestUtil;
import com.ebay.qa.util.WebEventListener;

public class TestBase1 {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    public  static EventFiringWebDriver e_driver;
    public static WebEventListener eventListener;

    public TestBase1(){
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/src/main/java/com/ebay"
                    + "/qa/config/config.properties");
            prop.load(ip);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void initialization(){
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

        if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\littin.jomon\\Documents\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe" );  
            driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        }
        /*else if(browserName.equals("FF")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/naveenkhunteta/Documents/SeleniumServer/geckodriver"); 
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        }*/


        e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        // Now create object of EventListerHandler to register it with EventFiringWebDriver
        eventListener = new WebEventListener();
        e_driver.register(eventListener);
        driver = e_driver;

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));

    }









}
```

==========================================================================
**console results:**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.11.0
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 22142
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
May 02, 2019 2:40:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Before navigating to: 'https://www.ebay.com/signin/'
Navigated to:'https://www.ebay.com/signin/'
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 25701
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
May 02, 2019 2:40:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Before navigating to: 'https://www.ebay.com/signin/'
Navigated to:'https://www.ebay.com/signin/'
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 6048
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
May 02, 2019 2:41:00 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Before navigating to: 'https://www.ebay.com/signin/'
Navigated to:'https://www.ebay.com/signin/'
FAILED: EbaylogoimgTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SigninPageTest.EbaylogoimgTest(SigninPageTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

FAILED: SigninPageTitleTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SigninPageTest.SigninPageTitleTest(SigninPageTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Got this exception. Have 3 test cases, each one opens the browser but does not execute TC's. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: please also share your `SigninPage` class and `TestBase1`, i think it's a error of driver because may be in your POM class you are not able to pass the driver instance, so i will suggest you that in your POM make parameterized constructor then from test class pass that driver parameter. and remove your test class non-paramterized constructor there is no use of it.

Comment: Hey Thank you for the response,It did work with this suggestion by Joao Farias "this.signinPage = new SigninPage(); " But i just want to know your suggestion too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void setup() {
        initialization();
        SigninPage signinPage = new SigninPage();
    }
```

Here, you are assigning a *SiginPage* object to a *singinPage* **local** variable. This object is [eligible to be destroyed as soon as the method ends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352561/2252076).

What you probably want to do is to assign this object to an **attribute**.

```
this.signinPage = new SigninPage();
```

Attributes last as long as the object which holds them exists.

TestNG will instantiate a SigninPageTest object, call each one of the @Test methods, along with the hooks @Before/@After and only after the tests destroy the SigninPageTest object.

Comment: @Farias  That worked. Thank you for the help and the brief explanation

Comment: You are most welcome. Could you mark the answer as accepted? It really helps to keep the community motivated to answer.

Comment: Kinda of new to website and automation. Did I mark it as accepted.just want to verify. Thanks